# Swiping between html pages for Android app dev

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know this has been asked before but I can't get any of he examples to work.
Getting the slide transition to work where you have all the pages as separate html files seems very difficult to do? How does the next/prev part of the script know which of the other files is next?

For example, index.html should slide to 01_welcome.html - but how does it know that it's not 02_funds.html?

Thanks for any enlightenment you can give. Below is the script ( courtesy of a previous answer)  I've been trying to implement.

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function () {
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
    }
});
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function () {
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        }, true, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: The above code works with _multi-page model_, for _single page model_, you can add custom attributes `data-next="foo"` and `data-prev="bar"`. Those custom attributes hold next/prev pages file names. Retrieve their values to change pages. Which JQM version are you using btw?

Comment: Thanks Omar - I'm using JQM 1.4.3 So I'd need to code each page - that's not a problem as there are only 6 pages anyway. My JS is quite poor - can you advise where those custom attributes would sit in the above code - or would it be completely different?

Answer (score 2):

The code in your OP works well in *Multi-Page Model* environment, since all pages (div's) are present in DOM. For *Single Page Model*, you will need to tweak the code a bit as each page is an individual file. Another note, `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead.

The simplest solution is to add custom attributes to each page div, e.g.

```
<div data-role="page" data-next-page="services" data-prev-page="about">
```

Retrieve the values of the custom attributes on `swipe` and then load the target page.

```
$(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function (event) {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
        nextPage = activePage.data("next-page"),
        prevPage = activePage.data("prev-page");

    /* move to next page */
    if (event.type == "swipeleft" && nextPage) {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", nextPage + ".html");
    }

    /* move to previous page */
    if (event.type == "swiperight" && prevPage) {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", prevPage + ".html", {
            reverse: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Omar - so effectively:
So where we have "services" it would be the full title, i.e. "services.html"?

Comment: @Jimbly2 you're welcome. Test it and let me know in case you want to apply some changes. Edit: exactly, _services.html_ is next page you want to move to and _about.html_ is previous one.

Comment: @Jimbly2 it's possible to have full file name `data-next-page="services.html"` and remove `+ ."html"` from code. I guess it looks better.

Comment: Hi Omar - I still can't get it to function - should this work in a Mac browser ( Safari/Chrome )for testing?

Comment: @Jimbly2 it should work on any browser as long as you have jQM loaded. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: I think it's clashing with anther script - will report back! Thanks

Comment: It's clashing with this:

    <script type="text/javascript">
       if (document.location.protocol != 'https:')  
    document.write('\x3Cscript      
    src="http://musecdn2.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-
    1.8.3.min.js"   type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
     </script>

Is there a way to suppress the js error when i remove it? It doesn't affect the page performance at all - thanks Jim

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60163/discussion-between-omar-and-jimbly2).