# JQuery Mobile swipe event only firing every other swipe

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have set up a swipeleft event in my app to move between fields of a form.  All of the fields are dynamically generated, so I'm not swapping between pages, I'm clearing and re-generating all the DOM elements.  The problem is the swipe event only fires every other time I swipe on the page or if I touch or tap anything on the page.

Here's the code that sets up the events:

```
$(document).delegate("#scorePage", "pageshow", function() {
  $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 10;
  $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 30;
  $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold = 500;
  $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 75;
  $('#divFoo').on("swipeleft", swipeLeftHandler);
  $('#divFoo').on("swiperight", swipeRightHandler);
  tableCreate(traits[0].keyboardID);
});
```

For context, tableCreate is putting a dynamically generated table into `divFoo` that contains information a user can pick from.  Here's the event code itself:

```
function swipeLeftHandler() {
  $("#divFoo").empty();
  traitIndex++;
  tableCreate(traits[traitIndex].keyboardID);
}
```

Why is my swipe event only firing every other time there is a swipe on the page?

Primarily testing on Android right now, if that makes a difference.

**Edit** I'm using JQuery Mobile version 1.4.4

Comment: which version are you using? it's not correct to attach _swipe_ listeners in `pageshow`, they will be duplicated.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for pointing that out, that makes sense.  If the elements I'm attaching to are in a separate html file that I link to in index.html can I still use `deviceready` to attach these handlers?

Comment: Are you using Cordova? It should be something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25542805/1771795 for overriding swipe defaults, it should be wrapped in `mobileinit` event and placed in head after jQuery.js and before JQM.js

Comment: @Omar Yes I am using Phonegap/Cordova version 3.5.  I've modified the code so that the handlers should only be attaching once now, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around this problem by simply rolling my own implementation of these events.  There's some sample code on how to do something similar here:

https://snipt.net/blackdynamo/swipe-up-and-down-support-for-jquery-mobile/

If anyone else uses this code to fix my same problem, make sure to be aware that the article is implementing swipeup and swipedown so you will have to adapt it.  In the end, I'm not entirely sure about the differences between this code and the actual implementations of swipeleft and swiperight, but this works consistently so I'm cutting my losses and going with it.