# Jquery mobile swipe on single page uses first page targets

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, swipe

I've converted a multi-page app intro single pages and now the swipes keep using the first page's targets.

On my first page I have:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#firstPage', function() {
    $(document).on("swipeleft", function(event) {
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "secondPage.html", {
            transition: "fade"
        });
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $(document).on("swiperight", function(event) {
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "lastPage.html", {
            transition: "fade"
        });
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

With HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage" data-dom-cache="false">
<!--CONTENT -->
<!-- PAGE JS -->
</div>
```

It works on the firstpage, but when I get to the second page it uses the first targets - secondPage.html and lastPage.html

my secondPage has this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#secondPage', function() {
    console.log('showing tags');
    $(document).on("swipeleft", function(event) {
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "thirdPage.html", {
            transition: "fade"
        });
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $(document).on("swiperight", function(event) {
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "firstPage.html", {
            transition: "fade"
        });
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="secondPage" data-dom-cache="false">
<!--CONTENT -->
<!-- PAGE JS -->
</div>
```

Etc etc...

I must add that my js code on each page is before the closing `</div>` of the page...so is being loaded by AJAX.

I did have this working on multi-page template, but the app has become quite big and for simplicity I decided to split it into separate pages.

Comment: 1. Never use `pageshow` to attach listeners. 2. `pageshow` is deprecated and will be removed 3. Use one JS file with all your custom code and load it in `head` of each and every html file 4. Check next comment with a link to better solution(s)

Comment: 5. Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25542805/1771795

Comment: Wow...thanks Omar. Great solution. Will try it now. A million times better solution.

Comment: Just tried it - works perfectly thanks.
Should have thought of that...so simple.